# Compiling vs Static Linking

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I have these files : help.cpp  help.h  help.o  main.cpp 
and I want to create a static lib.

> help.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "help.h"

using namespace std;

void hello()
{
 cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

> help.h

```
#ifndef HELP_H
#define HELP_H

void hello();

#endif
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "help.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 hello();
return 0;
}
```

To create a static lib :

1. `ar rcs libST.a help.o`
2. `g++ main.cpp -L . -l ST #to create my binary`

   I ran it , it printed out

   ```
   hi
   ```
3. I thought why not to do like this: `g++ main.cpp libST.a` and it worked as well.

Please tell me, what is the difference between command 2 and 3?

Comment: The title is a little bit confusing , any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of both will be (almost) identical in this case, but there are a few differences.

```
g++ main.cpp -L . -l ST
```

This compiles main.cpp and attempts to link it against something called `libST`. This will search the whole linker search path (typically /usr/local/lib, /lib and /usr/lib), including the current directory (since you specified it with `-L`). Note that this may link against either a shared or a static library, as long as it's called libST.a or libST.so.

If libST didn't exist in the current folder, your linker would go searching in all other folders that it knew about too.

```
g++ main.cpp libST.a
```

This does the same, but you're explicitly giving a static library to link against. This won't search, and it won't possibly link against a shared library, it'll just pull the object files out of the archive and use those when linking.

Comment: 1.in both cases the content of the library will be copied in the final executable ?
2. Really , the difference is that in the 1st command it will also search for a *.so file and in the 2nd command I give the linker directly something to work with , without the need to search for something additional ?

Thank You

Comment: @Oleg - it depends really. You can configure the compiler to only pull in the bits that are being used, but yes, in both cases (given your specific first command), the library will be pulled in. Also, for (2), yes, the difference is just how the compiler will search for the library.

Comment: to pull in only the bits that are being used ... 
sounds new to me , could you give me the keyword to search for ?

Comment: I believe it's both `-ffunction-sections` and `--gc-sections`.